# Simple http call via cURL returns false

Tags: php, curl

So I'm trying to make this small API via http post method. But I'm facing little problems here.
I have this code which I'm using to make a http call to **domain.com/smsapp/service....**, but, I get a response as this :- **boolean false**
What might be wrong here? I have no idea what can go wrong here.

```
function sendSMS($message,$number)
{
  $id = "Dogbag";
  $service = "sms_api_call_receiver.php";
  $userip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  /*** Build the request parameters ***/
  $request="Send-Sms";
  $u="http://www.domain.com/smsapp/$service?id=$id" . "&message=" . $message . "&number=$number" . "&ip=" . $userip;
  $result = sendPost($u, $request);
  var_dump($u);
  return $result;
}//function

function sendPost($Url, $strRequest)
{
   // Initialisation
   $ch=curl_init();
   // Set parameters
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, urlencode($Url));
   // Return a variable instead of posting it directly
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   // Active the POST method
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1) ;
   // Request
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $strRequest);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 2);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
   // execute the connexion
   $result = curl_exec($ch);
   // Close it
   curl_close($ch);
   return $result;
}
```

**sms_api_call_receiver.php**

```
if(isset($_GET['message']))
{
    mail("myemail@gmail.com", "got", "message");
}
```

Neither I get any message, nor any errors. I only get boolean false.
Any suggestion on this is appreciated.

Comment: curl returns false on error. check `curl_error($ch)` to get details about the error.

Comment: @MarcB
The investigation returned this `Could not resolve host: (nil); Host not found`. But I'm pretty sure that my URL is valid.

Comment: you url-encoded the ENTIRE url. that turns `http://` into `http%3A%2F%2F` and now it's not a url anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:
in Function SendSMS :-

```
$u="www.domain.com/smsapp/$service?id=$id" . "&message=" . $message . "&number=$number" . "&ip=" . $userip;
```

and this in Function sendPost:-

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://" . urlencode($Url));
```